# AAD Authentication for SignalR Hub and invoke the hub Method from azure function

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using SignalR and calling the hub method from one of my Azure function. Now i want to implement AAD authentication for signalR and make the required changes in the azure function to invoke the method.

I went through lot of questions related to same and i dint find the complete working answer for this.

What should be the steps i need to follow to achieve this?